# unable to replace zeros in the last row of dataframe with mean of last three rows in respective columns while leaving non zero values as it is

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,3,0], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [11, 14,15,16], [0,0,19,0]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

So what I want to do is:

1. in the last row, wherever value is 0s, replace with the mean of previous three rows of the same column
2. if the value is not 0, then leave it as it is
3. Also all other 0's elsewhere should remain 0 only.

So the end result should look something like this:

```
  a b   c   d
  1 0   3   0
  5 6   7   8
  9 10  11  12
 13 14  15  16
 9  10  19  12
```

Here, all three 0s are replaced with the previous three values' mean. And 19 remains as it is.

What I am trying to do is:

```
if (df.iloc[-1].any()==0):
    df.iloc[-1] = df[-4:-1].mean()
else:
   pass
```

This did not change the values and no error was returned as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: so you want to fill the values of only **last row** If 0 is present in it?

Comment: exactly this is want i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be much easier if you just replace `0` with `NaN` then use `fillna` with rolling mean, and shift:

```py
>>> df.iloc[-1]=df.iloc[-1].replace(0, np.nan)
>>> df=df.fillna(df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
      a     b   c     d
0   1.0   0.0   3   0.0
1   5.0   6.0   7   8.0
2   9.0  10.0  11  12.0
3  13.0  14.0  15  16.0
4   9.0  10.0  19  12.0
```

Comment: nice use of replace and rolling

Comment: this will replace the 0's in the other rows of the dataset as well.... what i provided was only a sample from much larger dataset and there might me more 0s than just the 0's in the last row alone. but thanks so much for helping me :)

Comment: i guess, can I use `out = df.iloc[-1].replace(0, np.nan)`  ??

Comment: now in your code above, `out` with through error.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque, that is coming from the previous code, just use `df` instead of `out`, it will work. updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
last_row = df.iloc[-1]
df.iloc[-1] = np.where(last_row.eq(0), df.iloc[-4:-1].mean(), last_row)
```

This will take values from three previous rows' mean where last row is equal to 0 and from the last row itself otherwise, i.e., nonzero values will stay as is.

---

pandas' [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) can be similarly used:

```
last_row = df.iloc[-1]
df.iloc[-1] = last_row.where(last_row.ne(0), df.iloc[-4:-1].mean())
```

Where the last row's values are not equal to 0 will be replaced with the mean of previous three's mean.

Comment: thanks @Mustafa for this alternate solution. it's awesome too. but i would rather prefer not using np.where() as of now. might use in future as you gave me wonderful ideas.